# How to give IFS 2 chars to split based on both not separately in shell scripting?

Tags: shell, string, split

I use the below bash script to split string:

```
string='/dev/shm: 0%used(0MB/4003MB) /var/spool/site/storage/users: 64%used(64437MB/100760MB) /run/user/1001: 0%used(0MB/801MB) /run: 10%used(165MB/1601MB) /run/lock: 0%used(0MB/5MB) /run/user/112: 0%used(0MB/801MB) /sys/fs/cgroup: 0%used(0MB/4003MB) /: 80%used(40518MB/50364MB) (>80%) : WARNING '
IFS=' /' # delimit on [SPACE]/
set -f # disable the glob part
array=($string) # invoke the split+glob operator

for i in "${array[@]}"; do echo '/'$i; done
```

String is split based on `space` or `/`. What I want to achieve is to separate the string when there is literally both `[space]/` not each of them alone.

Comment: It is given by `Icinga2` to our shell script. Make changes in that way needs to be familiar with the process of `Icinga2`

Comment: @don_crissti Isn't it possible to do two charachter split with IFS?

Comment: See bash manpage about word splitting: `The shell treats each character of IFS as a delimiter, and splits the results of the other expansions into words using these characters as field terminators.` with the focus on _each_.

Comment: @don_crissti I directly changed the script output. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `awk` and specify `' /'` as your delimiter:

```
$ cat data
/dev/shm: 0%used(0MB/4003MB) /var/spool/site/storage/users: 64%used(64437MB/100760MB) /run/user/1001: 0%used(0MB/801MB) /run: 10%used(165MB/1601MB) /run/lock: 0%used(0MB/5MB) /run/user/112: 0%used(0MB/801MB) /sys/fs/cgroup: 0%used(0MB/4003MB) /: 80%used(40518MB/50364MB) (>80%) : WARNING
$ cat data | awk -F' /' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){print $i}}'
/dev/shm: 0%used(0MB/4003MB)
var/spool/site/storage/users: 64%used(64437MB/100760MB)
run/user/1001: 0%used(0MB/801MB)
run: 10%used(165MB/1601MB)
run/lock: 0%used(0MB/5MB)
run/user/112: 0%used(0MB/801MB)
sys/fs/cgroup: 0%used(0MB/4003MB)
: 80%used(40518MB/50364MB) (>80%) : WARNING
```

See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23114583/bash-script-split-string-using-regex-delimiter